# Request current users API token Django REST Framework

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django web app that is using the Django REST framework to generate various API endpoints. 
I can ensure only logged in users can view/read these endpoints, but now I am at the stage of development where I want users to **post** to the API using tokens. I have successfully done this, however, I have hard-coded the users token into the post request in Javascript... This worked for testing but obviously is not a good final solution.

Is it possible to request the current users token somehow? Could I then include this token in the POST request head automatically?

Thanks for any help/feedback in advance!!

**EDIT:**
I think I am close, but I am getting a few errors in my chrome console, and still can't retrieve token.

**Console Errors:**

```
toggleScript.js:25 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 
'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
    at getToken (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/defaults/toggleScript.js:25:7)
    at manageDefaults 
(http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/defaults/toggleScript.js:62:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://127.0.0.1:8000/defaults/:1:1)
getToken @ toggleScript.js:25
manageDefaults @ toggleScript.js:62
onclick @ (index):1
toggleScript.js:24 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ 415 
(Unsupported Media Type)
```

I have a button when pressed, will trigger the function to retrieve the token, and this is what is causing the error stack above.

**toggleScript.js**

```
function getToken(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/';
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  var data = JSON.stringify({"username": "myusername", "password": "mypassword"});
  xhr.send(data);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(json.token);
      }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framework provides an API endpoint for requesting a user's token, given a username and password. You can wire the view into your `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^auth-token/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

Then when you POST a valid username and password to that view it will return the token in a JSON response:

```
{ 'token' : '9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b' }
```

Your app can then store that and send it in subsequent requests.

An example of retrieving the token using JQuery (assuming the view was mapped to the path `^auth-token/` in your `urls.py`):

```
$.post('/auth-token/', { username: 'admin', password: 'whatever' }, function(data) {
    // Token available as data.token
});
```

If you try and post to the `auth-token` view from within an already authenticated session, Django will likely reject the request with a `CSRF token missing or incorrect` response. You should either ensure that the session is not authenticated when you retrieve the token, or you could potentially include the `X-CSRFToken` header in the request. You'd need to extract the value from the `csrftoken` cookie. For example (using JQuery and the [JQuery Cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/auth-token/",
    type: "POST",
    headers: { 
        "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken")  # Extract the csrftoken from the cookie
    },
    data:{ username: "admin", password: "whatever" },
    dataType:"json"
}).done(function(data) {
    // Token available as data.token
});
```

More info on obtaining an auth token [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#by-exposing-an-api-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks Will, how do I add the user name and password? I have tried to include it in the URL, but can't seem to find any documentation on this. Is it:
htttp//127.0.0.1:8000/obtain_auth_token/ username='admin' password='whatever'

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how to do it in JQuery. Hope that helps.

Comment: The thing to note is that the request to obtain the token must be a POST request and the username and password must be sent as either form data or as JSON in the body of that request (so not part of the URL).

Comment: Thanks again. It seems as though I am getting 403 forbidden because of the csrf token not being included? Any ideas on how to include this?

Comment: Ah yes, the `obtain_auth_token` view expects that you are not logged in (that the session is unauthenticated). If you are logged in, Django will expect the csrf header in the request, and will reject it if it's not present. I've updated the answer with that, plus an example of how you can include the csrf header. The value of the header you have to retrieve from a cookie - and the example uses the JQuery Cookie plugin to do that. It may just be easier instead to call the `obtain_auth_token` view before the user is logged in - assuming that is appropriate for your application.